# Fetch all the substrings that start with a particular string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to fetch all the substrings that start with a particular string. For example, if the string is "**sum([Calculation_8630212162300975])/zn(sum([Calculation_6310302163817118]))**", I should get the output as "**Calculation_8630212162300975**" and "**Calculation_6310302163817118**"

I tried the below code. It works fine when there is single instance of such strings. But in case of multiple occurrence it returns me the string starting with the first bracket till the last bracket. For the example mentioned above, it returns **Calculation_8630212162300975])/zn(sum([Calculation_6310302163817118**

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[([^)]+)\\]").matcher(formula);                                                                                    

while(m.find()) {

System.out.println(m.group(1));  

}
```

Comment: What's your rule to match ? And what have you done so far ?

Comment: `Calculation_\\d+`

Answer (score 0):

**A hard and forceful solution**

```
String value = "sum([Calculation_8630212162300975])/zn(sum([Calculation_6310302163817118]))";

    if(value.contains("sum")){
        String valueDum= value.substring(value.indexOf("sum")+3,value.length());

        if(valueDum.contains("sum")){
            String myFirstValue = valueDum.substring(0,valueDum.indexOf("/"));
            String mySecondValue = valueDum.substring(valueDum.indexOf("sum")+3,valueDum.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was just an example. The string not necessarily will be having a "/". I don't think this solution will work in every case. For example I can also encounter a string "sum([Calculation_8630212162300975])+zn(sum([Calculation_6310302163817118]))+[Calculation_8630212162300972]". In this case, i need to fetch Calculation_8630212162300975, Calculation_6310302163817118 and Calculation_8630212162300972

Comment: Implement your own logic on this.I already wrote that Its hard and forceful solution only for what you provided. I know this solution wont work on everything. Its only as per your question. Split them into an array then Grab up each of them. if I started giving solution for this, This will be a large project with lots of calculation and logic. If some problems came while implementing your logic, then you have to ask here.